# How to change font of a QMessageBox in Qt?

Tags: qt, qmessagebox

I was trying to build a simple application with a `QComboBox` and a `QPushButton`. The idea is to populate the `QComboBox` with a list of all available fonts in the system. When the user selects a font and presses the `QPushButton` then a `QMessageBox` appears with the font selected. Now how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is using the `setFont()` method of the `QMessageBox`

```
QMessageBox *msg = new QMessageBox(QMessageBox::Information, "Message with font",
                         "This message is in font: " + ui->comboBox->currentText(),
                          QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel, this);
QFont font = QFont(ui->comboBox->currentText());
msg->setFont(font);
msg->exec();
```

Where `combobox` is `QComboBox` used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [basic HTML markups](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/richtext-html-subset.html) when setting the text to your message box label. The markup supported by QLabel includes `<font>`.This method also allows more versatile formatting.

Comment: True. But I wanted to use some class methods, as a cleaner way of doing stuff.

Comment: I don't think that one of those methods is cleaner than the other. But it is up to you which way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As before suggested you could use styles in your Html blocks (in my example add style to the paragraphs):

```
QMessageBox.about(
    self,
    "About",
    "<font>"
    "<p style='font-family: Terminal'>An simple app.</p>"
    "<p style='font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman'>- PyQt</p>"
    "<p>- Qt Designer</p>"
    "<p>- Python3</p>",
)
```

Results in:
[QMessageBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2h8w.png)